# React - function working only on second click why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My column where I added OnClick function when I click

```
<Col onClick={()=>optionSelected("usermanagement")}
            className={
              currentSelection === "usermanagement" ? "selectedOp" : "option"
            }
            tabIndex="-1"
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          >
```

Well, This may look dumb way to access the route but I want this for some other purpose .

```
 function optionSelected(optionName) {
    if (optionName === "usermanagement") {
      setCurrentSelection("usermanagement");
      history.push("/" + currentSelection);
    }
    if (optionName === "foodcatalog") {
      setCurrentSelection("foodcatalog");
      history.push("/" + currentSelection);
    }
    if (optionName === "promotions") {
      setCurrentSelection("promotions");
      history.push("/" + currentSelection);
    }
    if (optionName === "tickets") {
      setCurrentSelection("tickets");
      history.push("/" + currentSelection);
    }
    if (optionName === "reports") {
      setCurrentSelection("reports");
      history.push("/" + currentSelection);
    }
   }
```

Why I can access the page (history push) only on the second click ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Because react bundles setState calls together asynchronously. So by the time the code reaches `history.push`, `currentlySelection` hasn't changed yet.

change `history.push("/" + currentSelection);` to `history.push("/" + "reports");`
(or whatever route you are trying to get to)

Comment: Thanks a lot... Thought the dynamic way would be a pro way to call the route.. lol !

Comment: if you want to do it like this then you can put `history.push("/" + currentSelection);` in a `useEffect` and have the state as dependency and it'll change route once state updates. or write a function that does the same code and just call it with a different arg